# Does the sentence "the computer on the desk broken by my little sister is mine." have two meanings?

Tags: meaning, attachment-ambiguity

This is the main sentence, "The computer on the desk broken by my little sister is mine."

Does it theoretically have two meanings?
What is broken by my little sister is the computer, or the desk?

It seems to me that both are theoretically possible.

Comment: Theoretically, yes. It would be possible to use commas to make the intended meaning clearer.

Comment: What if I say "The computer that my father put on the desk broken by my little sister is mine.", does it still have theoretically two meanings like "the desk broken by my little sister" or "the computer that my father put on the desk is broken" ? I know this sentence is unnecessarily pushed into clumsy structures but I'm curious about possible meanings and the flexibility of the clauses.

Comment: "The computer that my father put on the desk, broken by my sister, is mine." - but I can't imagine anyone actually saying it that way in real life.

Comment: What if I don't use commas there, then?

Comment: Without the commas I don't think anyone would understand the computer to be broken.

Comment: But a native speaker said that this is grammatical, however not used at all. Theoretically it can refer to the computer, however we dont use this kind of word order, he said.

Comment: You didn't ask whether it was grammatical, just whether it was ambiguous. I have already told you that no-one would say that in real life.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could have either meaning. Although I would expect that a 'broken' desk would no longer be in condition to have a computer on top.

Honestly, putting all these ideas (that the computer is yours, that the little sister broke it and that it is on the desk) into a single sentence is either going to be ambiguous or awkward. Any two of them wouldn't be too bad but all three is different.

Comment: *My computer, which my little sister broke yesterday, is on the desk in Mom's office.*

Comment: "Desk for sale by lady with one loose leg" was a correction exercise in a school book when I was 9.

Comment: What if I say "The computer that my father put on the desk broken by my little sister is mine.", does it still have theoretically two meanings like "the desk broken by my little sister" or "the computer that my father put on the desk is broken" ? I know this sentence is unnecessarily pushed into clumsy structures but I'm curious about possible meanings and the flexibility of the clauses.